# SQL Syntax clarification on Row_Number and CTE Table Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Based on every state, i need to get the total rxnumber associated with that state.

I tried my syntax, but it is not picking the Max (RxNumber ) associated with a state.

```
with cte as
(
    select [State],
           RxNumber,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [State] 
                             ORDER BY [RxNumber]  Desc)  as [RowCount]
           from dbo.RxNumberState
)
select [State], MAX([RowCount]) as [TotalRx] 
from cte 
Group By [State],[RxNumber]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `RXNUMBER` from your `GROUP BY` clause

Try this...

```
with cte as
(
select      [State],
            RxNumber
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [State] ORDER BY [RxNumber]  Desc)  as [RowCount]
            from
dbo.RxNumberState
)
select [State]
,MAX([RowCount]) as [TotalRx] 
, MAX(RXNUMBER) MAX_RXNUMBER
from cte 
Group By [State]
```

---

A better way to write this would be the following, should solve your purpose

```
select [State]
, COUNT(RXNUMBER) as [TotalRx] 
, MAX(RXNUMBER) MAX_RXNUMBER
from dbo.RxNumberState
Group By [State]
```

Incase there are multiple entries of the same `RXNUMBER` then use `COUNT(DISTINCT RXNUMBER)`

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should give you ideas:

```
with cte as
(
    select distinct [State],
        rank() OVER(partition by [State] order by [State])  as [StateNumber]
    from dbo.RxNumberState
    group by [State]
)
select 
    r.[State],
    count(*) as [TotalRx] 
from dbo.rxNumberState r
join cte c on c.[State] = r.[State]
Group By r.[State]
```